# Synchronize the scene with the workspace (layout) in Blender 2.8

Tags: interface, scene, workspaces, navigation

As Blender was upgraded from 2.79 to 2.8, the scene's dependence on the workspace(layout) was removed and separated.

Nice update but I found it uncomfortable compared to 2.79.
Below I will describe in detail the inconvenience I feel.

**First is 2.79.**

Imagine you have several animation scenes and one vse scene in one blend file.
For animation, create a layout with a dopesheet, graph editor, and connect the scenes here.
Then create a layout for video editing to aggregate the animated scenes and attach the vse scenes to them.
This allows each scene to have a layout for one purpose and allows quick and easy navigation of the entire scene with the `Ctrl + arrow keys` shortcut.

> 2.79 case GIF example
>   [image]

**Next is 2.8.**
Workspaces and scenes work completely independently, so you'll have to click several times to change the scene and get the right workspace.
I feel this thing uncomfortable.
*(Of course, if you create workspaces based on the workflow in one scene, I know that this feature comes in handy.)*

> 2.8 case GIF example
>   [image]

So it's a question.
Can I navigate a blend file by syncing the workspace and scenes in Blender 2.8?

Thank you in advance.